# CosmosDB Container without PartitionKey

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Azure Cosmos DB .NET SDK Version 3.0 and I want to create container programmatically without partition key. Is it possible? I always got error saying Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: partitionKey

I use method CosmosContainers.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Seems like it. As long as it is not a bad idea to have primary key as a partition key, it's okay. And cross-partition queries are still doable. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Hi,if my answer is helpful, you could accept it for answer.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Done. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reproduce your issue on my side always.

[image]

Notice the exception is caused by below method:

[image]

Try to deserialize the dll source code and find the detailed logical code.

[image]

It seems we can't cross this judgement so far because cosmos db team is planning to deprecate ability to create non-partitioned containers, as they do not allow you to scale elastically.（Mentioned in my previous case:[Is it still a good idea to create comos db collection without partition key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55138025/is-it-still-a-good-idea-to-create-comos-db-collection-without-partition-key/55138587#55138587)）

But you still could create non-partitioned containers with [DocumentDB .net package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-dotnet-samples) or [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/).

Comment: Seems like it. As long as it is not a bad idea to have primary key as a partition key, it's okay. And cross-partition queries are still doable. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @MisaKovar You're so kind, you could mark it for answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Done. Thank you!