# How to create single partitioned collection in Cosmos DB using Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm working with Azure Cosmos DB, and I need to fetch all the documents of a particular collection of database. So that for executing a stored procedure they ask to enter partition key value, but I need the query result without any filter.

How can I create a collection for a particular database without mentioning the partition key? I'm accessing Cosmos DB in https://portal.azure.com/. I have to create a collection from that UI itself, not from code.

Comment: Is your question about executing a stored procedure in a partitioned collection or creating a single partitioned collection in Azure Portal?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,about stored procedure execution needs partition key.You could find the below clear statements in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#scope-of-a-transaction):

> If a stored procedure is associated with an Azure Cosmos container,
>   then the stored procedure is executed in the transaction scope of a
>   logical partition key. Each stored procedure execution must include a
>   logical partition key value that corresponds to the scope of the
>   transaction. For more information, see Azure Cosmos DB partitioning
>   article.

Secondly,in the past,you could create non-partitioned collection on the portal.But now, you can't.Please see my previous case:[Is it still a good idea to create comos db collection without partition key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55138025/is-it-still-a-good-idea-to-create-comos-db-collection-without-partition-key/55138587#55138587). Based on your description,you don't want partitioned collection.So, please create non-partitioned collection by Cosmos DB SDK. Such as:

```
DocumentCollection collection = new DocumentCollection();
collection.set("id","jay");
ResourceResponse<DocumentCollection> createColl = client.createCollection("dbs/db",collection,null);
```